DB Link from Oracle 12c running on Solaris to MariaDb with dialog authentication method
I have Oracle 12c running on Solaris which is my main database for multiple systems and data processing. There is planned upgrade and migration from Solaris but this wont happen soon, my team is not responsible for this.
I need to create Database link to MariaDB. This MariaDB Server is owned by different team and run some third party system for me.
The problem is MariaDB is configured with dialog authentication method which is not supported by MySQL. This means I cannot use MySQL driver,  only MariaDB driver. Unfortunately i cannot find any drivers for Solaris.
The only solution I can image is to download source of MariaDB driver and build for Solaris but this is tricky for me.
Is there any other solution i can use?
